# Git doesn't remove files from remote

Tags: git

I've removed some stuff (including directories and files) in my local branch.

When I commit, it says:

```
mauricio@mauricio-ubuntu:/var/www/moke$ git commit -m "Better implementation"
[ajax_branch 1a407ad] Better implementation
 56 files changed, 23465 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
```

Then I push:

```
mauricio@mauricio-ubuntu:/var/www/moke$ git push origin ajax_branch 
Counting objects: 25, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 7.97 KiB, done.
Total 18 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:giordanoapps/moke.git
   17f53bb..1a407ad  ajax_branch -> ajax_branch
```

But the files I've deleted in my local branch **keeps** in remote branch.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean that the files you deleted locally are kept in the remote branch? How can you tell? Also, ***how did you delete them in the first place***?

Comment: I've simply used rm -rf.

According to github, it keeps there...

Comment: you need to use "git rm" to basically add deleted files to a commit

Comment: "8 deletions" does not mean 8 files deleted, it means 8 lines of code were deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the deletion before commit.

```
git add -A
```

Comment: Note that if you want more precision, you can use `git rm <path/to/file>`.

Comment: Or if file is already deleted then `git rm --cached <path/to/file>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git rm folder/filename.ext` to better effect.

Then when you push to the remote folder, the changes will be recorded.